# Scheduled Query Fails To Read Spreadsheet

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 14 scheduled queries that run hourly from Google Sheets but they fail half of the time. I don't understand the error status though as the queries do run successfully half of the time. The error reads:

```
Error status: Invalid value Error while reading table: tester-253410.test1.Table_View_2_Agent_Targets, error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Errors: Deadline=118.888051456s; JobID: tester-253410:5e59a150-0000-2421-b469-001a1144591c
```

Is there anything that I can try?

[image: Stackdriver monitoring 1]
[image: Stackdriver monitoring 2]
[image: Stackdriver monitoring 3]

Comment: The issue seems related to the  table "Table_View_2_Agent_Targets", the table exists?, do you have enough permissions to query this table? Try to query  just the table, I suggest to try to avoid the use of this table in your query only to make a test and corroborate that the table is the provoking the issue.

Comment: Hi, the scheduled query on that table works half the time though? I have permissions to it as it's mine. I also queried it on it's own and then it works half the time as well.

Comment: Always fails with the same error message? Did you verify the job ID  in Stackdriver logging monitoring? Maybe there you could find a clue.

Comment: I have attached the Stackdriver monitoring but I'm not sure if that's what you are referring too and I'm not sure how to interpret it. But in the meanwhile I tried a couple of things and I'm seeing some improvement as they only fail about 25% of the time now. But they all have exactly the same error:  **Error status: Error while reading table: tester-253410.test1.KBY_Agent_Targets, error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Errors: Deadline=119.114010965s; JobID: 506489078692:scheduled_query_5e73a8e6-0000-2b9b-b096-001a11481c5e**    **

Comment: According to the error message the issue is happening when BigQuery tries to read the spreadsheet INVALID_VALUE:"Failed to read the spreadsheet"; nonetheless, this error is very generic, since you have checked the spreadsheet is well formed and queried it without issues, if you are using "SELECT *" could you try to use only 1 or  2 fields per table to validate if the issue could be related to a specific column in the table  " tester-253410.test1.Worcester_Agent_Targets"